# Slow reading speed of GATT characteristics BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a project to transfer data between a Bluetooth device (TI CC2650) and android. To do this, it is necessary to perform a reading of the GATT characteristic at a speed of at least 24 kbps. The Bluetooth Low Energy specification allows this transfer rate. 
I work in Android Studio and use standard libraries for BLE offered by the studio. When requesting a read from a master device, the characteristics of a slave device using the `mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic ()` or `mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic ()` command is at least 100 ms until the data is available. By increasing the size of the GATT characteristics, the time can reach 1500 ms. What is the reason for this limitation and how can it be circumvented?

Comment: [Continues of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533992/what-is-the-reason-for-the-slow-speed-of-processing-packets-of-information-recei)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read operation requires one roundtrip per chunk. And the round trip time is at least one multiple of the connection interval.

If you use notifications instead, you can pump such messages very fast since multiple packets can be sent every connection event. Also try increase mtu and use LE data length extention when possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried notifications, changed MTU and connection interval. After changing MTU Android begin to waste more time for processing big package. When I used notifications some packages has lost. I think that problem in Android. It can not process package in required time. Do you know how I can cope with it?

Comment: Android does not lose notification packets, so your problem must be somewhere else. You should look at the hci snoop log (which you can turn on in Android developer settings, and then transfer to a computer and look at it in Wireshark) to see all the timings and packets. Or even better, use an air sniffer.

Comment: Yes, Android does not lose notification, but sometimes it reads twice next package. For example, I sent three packages: first {1,2,3}, second {4,5,6}, third {7,8,9}. On Android recieve three packages too, but first {1,2,3}, second {7,8,9} and third {7,8,9}. Countity of packages is always correct. Possible, It is because package had been rewritten before our program saved previous package. What do you think about it?