# What is the reason for the slow speed of processing packets of information received by Android via Bluetooth Low Energy?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

The task is to transfer information from a chip with BLE 4.0 to an Android device at high speed (at least 24 kbps). Bluetooth specification allows it. We used two methods: write / read (we write the request into one characteristic, the answer is read from the other) and notify (the chip constantly transmitted packets with a frequency of 50 ms). In the case of write / read, the time for rewriting and reading a packet varies in the region of 100 ms. When using notify, the time was set to 50 ms, but Android was losing packets. Instead, he received the old values ​​of the packets, or missed and read the next one twice, although the chip accurately sent notifications with new values. How can I solve or work around this problem?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                stopT =System.currentTimeMillis();
                //double td=stopT-startT;

                time1.add(stopT - startT);
                //double td = Math;
                double sum = 0;
                for(int i =0;i<time1.size();i++) sum+= time1.get(i);
                double td = sum/time1.size();
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                textView3.setText(String.valueOf(td));
                displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));

                //for (int i = 0; i < BluetoothLeService.byteArray.length; i++) time.add(Double.valueOf(BluetoothLeService.byteArray[i]));

                float[] floatArray = new float[BluetoothLeService.byteArray.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < BluetoothLeService.byteArray.length; i++) floatArray[i] = (float)BluetoothLeService.byteArray[i];
                float[] tmp = new float[time2.length + floatArray.length];
                System.arraycopy(time2, 0, tmp, 0, time2.length);
                System.arraycopy(floatArray, 0, tmp, time2.length, floatArray.length);
                time2 = tmp;

                if (cnt1 < 51) {
                    Matr[cnt1]=floatArray;
                    cnt1++;
                }


                if (flag == 1) {
                    startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic();
                    mBluetoothLeService.writeCustomCharacteristic(hex);
                }
                if(flag_notify == 1)startT = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_CHARACTERISTIC_WRITE.equals(action)) {
                mBluetoothLeService.readCustomCharacteristic();
            }
        }
    };

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

        // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
        // carried out as per profile specifications:
        // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
            int format = -1;
            if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
            } else {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
            }
            final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
        } else {
            // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
            final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            byteArray =data;
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for(byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

BluetoothGattCallback:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                //gatt.requestMtu(512);
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                          BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_CHARACTERISTIC_WRITE, characteristic);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };
```

Upd.: Changes in Callback function.

```
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            StopT = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (cnt1 < kolvo) {
                save[cnt1]=characteristic.getValue();
                td1 [cnt1] = StopT - StartT;
                StartT = System.currentTimeMillis();

                cnt1++;
            }
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please show the code so we can see if you have done anything wrong?

Comment: Hi, Emil! We discussed about this question in another theme  [Slow reading speed of GATT characteristics BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477822/slow-reading-speed-of-gatt-characteristics-ble). We attach part of code where we use recieved package.

Comment: Can you also post the code that shows how the BluetoothGattCallback calls the broadcastUpdate method?

Comment: @Emil, I attached BluetoothGattCallback

Comment: Your flow for the variable "byteArray" doesn't work. If you get two consecutive notifications, the second notification might overwrite the previous value before the first intent is handled, since broadcasts are queued up and are executed "as soon as possible".

Comment: @Emil, we have made some changes in Callback function. I attached it in the end of post. Is it correct? We changed also min/max connection interval and now we have this situation: on interval 50 ms, packages did not lose, but on interval 20 ms we have 1,7% of lost packages. What's wrong? We will try to check packages sending from our device, but device manufacturer try to assure us  that it is not problem from device side.

Comment: Did you look at the Android HCI snoop log? There you should see all packets on a more lower level, before they are handled by the Android OS. That way you can identify if the packet gets lost later in the chain, or if the remote device never sent it.